# AutoCAD .net Side loading a dwg with ReadDwgFile then Plotting

Tags: c#, autocad

I used the example [here](http://spiderinnet1.typepad.com/blog/2013/03/autocad-net-read-dwg-into-memory-using-databasereaddwgfile.html) to side load dwgs into memory combined with the example [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-6E0B1F7B-7B0E-4E3E-B1FD-018E0A3673BE) of Plot From Model Space. I got things working except for the plots are not respecting whether the layers are frozen or not and printing as if they were all thawed. The data coming in from the dwg is correct. I can iterate the layers while debugging and verify the correct ones are either frozen or thawed. Also If I just saveas the dwg to a new name it matches the original concerning the layer state.Any Ideas?

```
[CommandMethod("PlotLayout")]
    public static void PlotLayout()
    {
        // Get the current document and database, and start a transaction
        Document acDoc = Active.Document;
        Database acCurDb = Active.Database;
        Editor ed = Active.Editor;
        var collection = new List<string>() { "C:\\Test\\440001A.dwg", "C:\\Test\\440001B.dwg", "C:\\Test\\440001C.dwg", "C:\\Test\\440001D.dwg" };
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            var dwg = collection[i];
            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dwg);
            var fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dwg);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(dir, fn + "-" + i.ToString() + ".pdf");
            Database oldDb = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
            using (Database db = new Database(false, true))
            {
                db.ReadDwgFile(dwg, FileOpenMode.OpenForReadAndAllShare, false, null);
                db.CloseInput(true);


                using (Transaction acTrans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                    try
                    {
                        HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase = db;

                        LayoutManager acLayoutMgr = LayoutManager.Current;

                        // Get the current layout and output its name in the Command Line window
                        Layout acLayout = acTrans.GetObject(acLayoutMgr.GetLayoutId(acLayoutMgr.CurrentLayout),
                                                            OpenMode.ForRead) as Layout;

                        // Get the PlotInfo from the layout
                        using (PlotInfo acPlInfo = new PlotInfo())
                        {
                            acPlInfo.Layout = acLayout.ObjectId;

                            // Get a copy of the PlotSettings from the layout
                            using (PlotSettings acPlSet = new PlotSettings(acLayout.ModelType))
                            {
                                acPlSet.CopyFrom(acLayout);

                                // Update the PlotSettings object
                                PlotSettingsValidator acPlSetVdr = PlotSettingsValidator.Current;

                                // Set the plot type
                                acPlSetVdr.SetPlotType(acPlSet, Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.PlotType.Extents);

                                // Set the plot scale
                                acPlSetVdr.SetUseStandardScale(acPlSet, true);
                                acPlSetVdr.SetStdScaleType(acPlSet, StdScaleType.ScaleToFit);

                                // Center the plot
                                acPlSetVdr.SetPlotCentered(acPlSet, true);

                                // Set the plot device to use
                                acPlSetVdr.SetPlotConfigurationName(acPlSet, "DWF6 ePlot.pc3", "ANSI_B_(11.00_x_17.00_Inches)");

                                // Set the plot info as an override since it will
                                // not be saved back to the layout
                                acPlInfo.OverrideSettings = acPlSet;

                                // Validate the plot info
                                using (PlotInfoValidator acPlInfoVdr = new PlotInfoValidator())
                                {
                                    acPlInfoVdr.MediaMatchingPolicy = MatchingPolicy.MatchEnabled;
                                    acPlInfoVdr.Validate(acPlInfo);

                                    // Check to see if a plot is already in progress
                                    if (PlotFactory.ProcessPlotState == ProcessPlotState.NotPlotting)
                                    {
                                        using (PlotEngine acPlEng = PlotFactory.CreatePublishEngine())
                                        {
                                            // Track the plot progress with a Progress dialog
                                            using (PlotProgressDialog acPlProgDlg = new PlotProgressDialog(false, 1, true))
                                            {
                                                using ((acPlProgDlg))
                                                {
                                                    // Define the status messages to display 
                                                    // when plotting starts
                                                    acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.DialogTitle, "Plot Progress");
                                                    acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelJobButtonMessage, "Cancel Job");
                                                    acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.CancelSheetButtonMessage, "Cancel Sheet");
                                                    acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetSetProgressCaption, "Sheet Set Progress");
                                                    acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.SheetProgressCaption, "Sheet Progress");

                                                    // Set the plot progress range
                                                    acPlProgDlg.LowerPlotProgressRange = 0;
                                                    acPlProgDlg.UpperPlotProgressRange = 100;
                                                    acPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 0;

                                                    // Display the Progress dialog
                                                    acPlProgDlg.OnBeginPlot();
                                                    acPlProgDlg.IsVisible = true;

                                                    // Start to plot the layout
                                                    acPlEng.BeginPlot(acPlProgDlg, null);

                                                    // Define the plot output
                                                    acPlEng.BeginDocument(acPlInfo, acDoc.Name, null, 1, true, "c:\\myplot");

                                                    // Display information about the current plot
                                                    acPlProgDlg.set_PlotMsgString(PlotMessageIndex.Status, "Plotting: " + acDoc.Name + " - " + acLayout.LayoutName);

                                                    // Set the sheet progress range
                                                    acPlProgDlg.OnBeginSheet();
                                                    acPlProgDlg.LowerSheetProgressRange = 0;
                                                    acPlProgDlg.UpperSheetProgressRange = 100;
                                                    acPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 0;

                                                    // Plot the first sheet/layout
                                                    using (PlotPageInfo acPlPageInfo = new PlotPageInfo())
                                                    {
                                                        acPlEng.BeginPage(acPlPageInfo, acPlInfo, true, null);
                                                    }

                                                    acPlEng.BeginGenerateGraphics(null);
                                                    acPlEng.EndGenerateGraphics(null);

                                                    // Finish plotting the sheet/layout
                                                    acPlEng.EndPage(null);
                                                    acPlProgDlg.SheetProgressPos = 100;
                                                    acPlProgDlg.OnEndSheet();

                                                    // Finish plotting the document
                                                    acPlEng.EndDocument(null);

                                                    // Finish the plot
                                                    acPlProgDlg.PlotProgressPos = 100;
                                                    acPlProgDlg.OnEndPlot();
                                                    acPlEng.EndPlot(null);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {

                        ed.WriteMessage(ex.ToString());
                    }
                HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase = oldDb;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works if BACKGROUNDPLOT is set to 2 (but only the first drawing is plotted). If BACKGROUNDPLOT is set to 0, all drawing are plotted, but the frozen layer are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but I found a work around. If I iterate the LayerTable, check for frozen then make IsPlottable false it prints correctly. If a better soultion is available please let me know. Thanks

```
 LayerTable _LayerTable = acTrans.GetObject(db.LayerTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as LayerTable;
                         foreach (ObjectId _LayerTableId in _LayerTable)
                         {
                             LayerTableRecord _LayerTableRecord =
                                        (LayerTableRecord)acTrans.GetObject(_LayerTableId,
                                                            OpenMode.ForWrite);
                             if (_LayerTableRecord.IsFrozen)
                             {
                                 _LayerTableRecord.IsPlottable = false;
                             }
                         }
```